# Deploy with war to tomcat with jenkins

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to deploy my war file after Jenkins build it with Gradle. so I used the [deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin). as far as i know i should create a post build action in my task configuration in jenkins. i created that like this:
[image: my post build action to deploy]
and I checked that the war file is there.
but its not working and the war is not deployed anywhere and there is no sign of any effort from jenkins to deploy the artifact to the tomcat. here is the console output of my task:
[image: jenkins output]
which are all about build actions not post build actions!

anybody can help?
where can i see logs of jenkins post build actions?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there was a problem with the path to the war file!
although it's relative to `~/.jenkins/jobs/MyJob/workspace/` but it's not working
I changed that to `**/*.war` and works now!!